# Authenticating API calls using requests and requests-oauthlib in Python 3.3

Tags: python, api, oauth, python-requests

I'm trying to write my own Cryptsy API wrapper in Python 3 using the requests and requests-oauthlib libraries. I'm new to both API calls and Python. As it stands, I get this error:

```
{'error': 'Unable to Authorize Request - Check Your Post Data', 'success': '0'}
```

Which is unsurprising, because I've had a hard time finding documentation on calling/signing authenticated API requests using these libraries. I'm not quite sure where to start.

Here's a snippet of my code:

```
import time
import requests
from requests-oauthlib import OAuth1Session

class Cryptsy:

    def __init__(self, APIKey, Secret):
        self.APIKey = APIKey
        self.Secret = Secret
        self.privateBaseURL = 'https://api.cryptsy.com/api'

    def private_api_query(self, method, payload={}):
        url = self.privateBaseURL
        session = OAuth1Session(self.APIKey, client_secret=self.Secret)
        payload['method'] = method
        payload['nonce'] = int(time.time())
        response = session.post(url, data=payload)
        js = response.json()
        return js

    def getMarkets(self):
        return self.private_api_query('getmarkets')
```

As you can see, I'm vaguely aware of nonce, but I'm unsure if it's even necessary while using these libraries. I'm aware the request needs to be signed, but unsure of how to get these libraries to do that in the way I need.

Of course, I could always try to use urllib, but I've had trouble with it since switching to Python 3, and I like the (supposed) straightforwardness of the requests library.

More information on Cryptsy's API can be found here: https://www.cryptsy.com/pages/api

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Looking at the Cryptsy API documentation seems to suggest that Cryptsy don't use OAuth at all. I see no reference to it in their docs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Cryptsy doesn't use OAuth (at least their docs don't claim they do). Instead, they roll their own authentication. Leaving aside the security of that approach for a moment, let's take a look at what you need.

Their documentation isn't great, but from my reading of ityYou need:

- two extra headers: **Key** (containing your public API key) and **Sign** (containing a HMAC-SHA512 signature of the body)
- A request body with content type `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` which contains the method name, the method parameters and a nonce.

Making this work in requests is a bit less simple than usual, but the easiest way to do it is probably to write your own custom [Authentication handler](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/user/advanced/#custom-authentication). Here's an example:

```
from requests.auth import AuthBase
import hmac
import hashlib
import time

class CryptsyAuth(AuthBase):
    """Authenticates a given HTTP request using the Cryptsy Auth scheme"""
    def __init__(self, api_key, api_secret):
        self.key = api_key
        self.secret = api_secret

    def __call__(self, r):
        r.body += '&nonce=%d' % int(time.time())
        h = hmac.new(self.secret, r.body, hashlib.sha512).hexdigest()

        r.headers['Key'] = self.key
        r.headers['Sign'] = h
        return r
```

Note that this auth handler will fall over if you don't provide a request body, but that's ok because Cryptsy mandates that you do. Here's how you use it:

```
class Cryptsy:

    def __init__(self, APIKey, Secret):
        self.APIKey = APIKey
        self.Secret = Secret
        self.privateBaseURL = 'https://api.cryptsy.com/api'
        self.session = requests.Session()

    def private_api_query(self, method, payload={}):
        url = self.privateBaseURL
        payload['method'] = method
        response = self.session.post(url, data=payload, auth=CryptsyAuth(self.APIKey, self.Secret))
        js = response.json()
        return js

    def getMarkets(self):
        return self.private_api_query('getmarkets')
```

Comment: This works great! Thank you so much. The only change I had to made was to encode the hmac parameters as bytes. `h = hmac.new(bytes(self.secret, 'utf-8'), bytes(r.body, 'utf-8'), hashlib.sha512).hexdigest()`